# Buscar con recursividad en un objeto

Tags: recursión

Hola tengo este ejercicio que ha sido un dolor de cabeza no logro resolverlo.
Tengo que buscar de forma recursiva en un objeto.
Me pasan por parámetro el objeto en cuestión y un string con el que tengo que compara para ver si se haya dentro de mi objeto.
Esta en la funcion con los parametros que me pasan:

```
function seleccionarPelicula(peliculas, nombrePelicula, i = 0) {
 }
```

Y este es el objeto:

```
 var peliculas = {
 0: "El padrino",
 1: "Iron Man",
 2: "Terminator",
 3: "Rambo",
 4: "Creed"
}
```

Hasta ahora he intentado convertir el objeto en array para poder iterar sobre èl asi:

```
function seleccionarPelicula(peliculas, nombrePelicula, i = 0) {
var aux = Object.values(peliculas)

 }
```

Asi quedaria mi funcion segun mi logica:

```
function seleccionarPelicula(peliculas, nombrePelicula, i = 0) {
var aux = Object.values(peliculas)
if(aux[i] === nombrePelicula){
return aux[i]
}
else if(aux[i] === aux.length-1){
return
}
return seleccionarPelicula([i++]) 
 }
```

Ayuda plis!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas convertir el objeto ni retornar sus valores. Un objeto en javascript es también una "especie" de diccionario y un diccionario a su vez es una colección al igual que un array. Y un Objeto con propiedades numéricas es incluso mucho más parecido a un array

Por ejemplo

```
console.log( peliculas[2] ); // Imprime Terminator
```

Y si te fijas, es exactamente lo mismo como lo harías con un array.

Por otro lado tú tienes la forma más simple de recursión, que es a través de un índice. En este tipo de funciones recursivas generalmente habrán 3 condiciones `if`

1. Una condición de parada, para que no exista un bucle infinito, cuyo error da origen al nombre de esta página.
2. Una condición de "elemento encontrado", que retornará algún valor
3. Caso contrario volver a llamar la función sumando +1 al índice

El único truco en tu caso particular es el punto (1), como determinar la condición de parada? y es que cuando un indice no existe en javascript NO arroja error como en otros lenguajes, sino que retorna `undefined`

```
console.log( peliculas[9999]) //undefined
```

Entonces al saber que los números son correlativos,`peliculas[i]==undefined` será la condición de parada

Demo:

```js
var peliculas = { 0: "El padrino", 1: "Iron Man",2: "Terminator", 3: "Rambo", 4: "Creed"}

function seleccionarPelicula(peliculas, nombrePelicula, i = 0) {
  if(peliculas[i] == undefined) return null; //Si el indice no existe devolvemos null
  else if(peliculas[i] === nombrePelicula) return peliculas[i]; //encontrada la pelicula
  else return seleccionarPelicula(peliculas,nombrePelicula,++i); //no se ha encontrado la peliculas probamos con el siguiente
}

console.log(seleccionarPelicula(peliculas,"Rambo"));
console.log(seleccionarPelicula(peliculas,"asdasd"));
```

Comment: Aaa claro ya entendí mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

escribo una posible solución, pero no puedo probarla:

```js
  var peliculas = ["El padrino", "Iron Man", "Terminator", "Rambo", "Creed"]

  function seleccionarPelicula(peliculas, nombrePelicula) {
     var aux = Object.values(peliculas)
     if (peliculas[0] === nombrePelicula){
        return nombrePelicula
     } else if(peliculas.length == 0){
        return
     } else {
        return seleccionarPelicula(peliculas.slice(1)) 
     }
  }

 let p = seleccionarPelicula(peliculas, "Terminator")
  
  console.log(p);
```

Comment: Okis la pruebo yo, gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar una función con un iterador que examine el objeto, si no encuentra la película en la primera posición la función se llama a sí misma pero esta vez para evaluar la segunda posición. Si no se encuentra devuelve -1. Si la encuentra devuelve la respuesta en forma de un array [posicion,valor].

```
let peliculas = {
  0: "El Padrino",
  1: "Iron Man",
  2: "Terminator",
  3: "Rambo",
  4: "Creed"
}

let values = Object.values(peliculas) // Array con los valores del objeto 
values = values.entries() // Iterador

function search(name){ 
  let actual = values.next(); // elemento actual evaluado
  if(actual.done) return -1; // si no se encuentra el elemento devuelve -1
  if(actual.value[1] == name) return actual.value // si se encuentra, la devuelve
  return search(name) // recursividad
}

console.log(search("El Padrino"))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo